# For constrained devices, is JSON better than XML to transmit data between devices?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, jsonschema

When we look at a pure JSON or XML document of same information, XML tends to be slightly bigger because it contains opening/closing tags.

1. In this sense, for constrained devices (with super-small flash memory: e.g. 32KB), is JSON better than XML to transmit data between devices?
2. Or, are there any more aspects that I have to take into account apart from document size?

Thank you very much in advance.